# Can't return Get-ADUser property to variable

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm struggling right now with using `Get-ADUser`.  Things seem to work when I do it in the CLI:

```
PS C:\> $UserName = Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like "*Jen* Caruso"}
PS C:\> $UserName

DistinguishedName : CN=Jennifer Caruso,OU=Users,OU=Amistad
                    High,OU=AF-CT,OU=AF,DC=af,DC=org
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : Jennifer
Name              : Jennifer Caruso
ObjectClass       : user
ObjectGUID        : 4af56e81-49e1-497f-97f8-e609de783e6b
SamAccountName    : jennifercaruso
SID               : S-1-5-21-3170393226-1320018563-691763927-1543
Surname           : Caruso
UserPrincipalName : jennifercaruso@af.org

PS C:\> $UserName.SamAccountName
jennifercaruso
```

But when I use this in a ps1 script, I get nothing returned:

```psh
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$FName = "Jen"
$LName = "Caruso"
$UserName = "$FName$LName"

$ADName = Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like "*$FName* $LName"}
$User = $ADUser.SamAccountName

Write-Host "$UserName $User"
```

It's pretty confusing, and a little bit frustrating.  Am I overlooking something?

Comment: `$ADName` and `$ADUser` are 2 distinct variables, rename accordingly

Comment: Good catch - I was so exhausted I missed that.  Ansgar's answer also helped immensely in correcting my issue.  Specifically the 2nd part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the filter as a string instead of a scriptblock:

```
$ADName = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '*$FName* $LName'"
```

Expand the property `SamAccountName` to get the account name without intermediate steps/variables:

```
$User = Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like '*$FName* $LName'" |
        select -Expand SamAccountName
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I didn't realize that I had used 2 different AD-related variables, but your 2nd bit of code was spot-on!